# To have validation for checked box list using jquery

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-core

I have an ASP.Net core application which has multiple check box lists and I need to check if each of them have atleast one option selected.

So this is my view :

```
for (int i = 0; i < Model.Fruits.Count; i++)
{
    <input asp-for="Fruits[i].Selected" type='checkbox' class="chkbox" />
}
<text>@Model.Fruits[i].FruitText</text>   
<span class="text-danger"></span>


for (int i = 0; i < Model.Vegetables.Count; i++)
{
    <input asp-for="Vegetables[i].Selected" type='checkbox' class="chkbox" />
}
<text>@Model.Vegetables[i].VegetablesText</text>   
<span class="text-danger"></span>

for (int i = 0; i < Model.Flowers.Count; i++)
{
    <input asp-for="Flowers[i].Selected" type='checkbox' class="chkbox" />
}
<text>@Model.Flowers[i].FlowersText</text>   
<span class="text-danger"></span>
```

So I tried something like this.

```
 $("#btnSave").on("click", function () {

    $(".chkbox").each(function () {
        if($(this).is(':checked') == false)
        {
            $(this).closest('span').text("Please select atleast one option");
            return
        }
    });

    $("#form").submit();
});
```

So how do I change my script? Or is there a need to change how my view/models are structured?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing you can try is to wrap all your lists of checkboxes in `div's` and then iterate through those `div's` to see if at least one of the `checkboxes` is `checked`. If every `div` has at least one `checkbox` that's `checked` you `submit` the `form`.

```
<div class="chkbox-list">
for (int i = 0; i < Model.Fruits.Count; i++)
{
    <input asp-for="Fruits[i].Selected" type='checkbox' class="chkbox" />
    <text>@Model.Fruits[i].FruitText</text> 
}
    <span class="text-danger"></span>
</div>

... other divs for Vegetables and Flowers
```

Then you can traverse all the `div's` as follows:

```
$('#btn-save').on('click', function() {
  let atLeastOneCheckedPerDiv = true
  $('.chkbox-list').each(function() {
    let div = $(this)
    let countChecked = div.find('.chkbox').filter(function() {
      return $(this).is(":checked")
    }).length
    if (countChecked === 0) {
      // show error message
      div.find('.text-danger').text('Please select at least one option')
      atLeastOneCheckedPerDiv = false
    }
  })
  if (atLeastOneCheckedPerDiv) {
      // submit form
  }
})
```